# How to find the code violations for less and sass file?

Tags: sass, less, gulp-sass

I have searched to find the code violations tool for less and sass file as like fxcop and stylecop. But i am very confused and found the below links. Am trying to find the less and sass violations with this.

**Links:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-lint ,

https://github.com/lesshint/gulp-lesshint

Command i used to find the violations for less file is **lesshint "less file path"**

Could anyone please let me know the best tool or the way(direct me in right way) to find the code violations for .less and .scss (sass) files?

Comment: Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Any more information on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) to your `gulp-sass` (or LESS) task and it will print the error and it's location to the console. For example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

    gulp.task('sass', () => {
        return gulp.src('src/**/*.scss')        
            .pipe($.plumber({
                errorHandler: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    this.emit('end');
                }
            }))
            .pipe($.sass())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
    });
```